# Как в allure-framework указать папку с json-result

Tags: java, json, юнит-тесты, allure

Allure-report ссылается на папку allure-results которая находится в target, однако после прогона тестов эта папка появляется в src. Как указать папку allure-results для доступа.

Answer (score 0):

вам нужно положить в src/main/resources файл allure.properties и добавить туда параметр

allure.results.directory=<ваша директория>

у вас видимо так
allure.results.directory=src/allure-results

Так же вы можете указать путь до папки с результатами при генерации отчета (есть соответствующий параметр в jenkins-плагине или например из терминала при запуске команды allure serve - пример allure serve src/allure-results)